# How to share a Realm Database between a React Native app and a Share Extension

Tags: ios, react-native, realm

Is there a way to instantiate the Realm database in JavaScript using the React Native API so that it is accessible to the app group containing the main app and the Share Extension?

We are creating a React Native app that requires a Share Extension to import data to the app with our backend service. Our user authentication information is stored in a Realm database, and this information also needs to be accessed by the share extension in order to contact the service on the user's behalf.

Currently, the only way we have found to accomplish this, is to calculate the Realm path in `AppDelegate`, then pass it to our root component, as shown below:

```
NSURL *realmPathUrl = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.company.product"];
NSString *realmPath = [[realmPathUrl path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.realm"];
NSDictionary *props = @{@"realmPath" : realmPath};
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleName:@"product" initialProperties:props launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

And then in the root component:

```
const userPrefsRealmDatabase = new Realm({path: props.realmPath, ...otherOptions});
```

But this is a very messy solution, and introduces some problems with our Flux implementation, as Stores are instantiated before the root component, but require access to the Realm database.

Comment: I have a similar case, please can you share some details on how you did this? I would really appreciate that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating your own native module that exports the path as a constant, since that will be immediately available when your JS loads. See the [Exporting Constants](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#exporting-constants) section for how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, this is what we ended up doing and probably the best solution

Comment: Doing the same will solve the problem in Android too?

Comment: @JordanSchalm can you tell me how did you do that? I cannot access that document and in need to export realm to its npm package repo

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the react-native plugin https://github.com/realm/realm-js

Comment: Thanks, we are already using the React Native plugin, but it doesn't (appear to) have a native way to put the Realm into an app group's shared data folder. It allows you to specify a `path` for the Realm file on initialization, but so far as I can tell, that `path` must be calculated in the `AppDelegate`, which introduces a lot of complexity.